# Swipe-to-delete doesn't work but Alt+Swipe works

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I've added `commit editingStyle...` function to enable swipe left on UITableView cells. It doesn't work unless I hold ALT. Then two gray circles appear and I can swipe using the bottom one and delete button appears on the cell just fine.

[image]

What can be wrong?

Here's some code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        my-delete-func()

    }
}
```

I've tried adding `canEditRowAt indexPath -> return true` and `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false`. It didn't help.

Comment: Can you show your code.

Comment: two finger swipe? we need to see your code

Comment: I have a huge controller and not sure what to show. Added gif

Comment: @Maklaus: It may not actually be your code, but your device (is this iOS simulator?). The two gray dots you see are the pinch/explode indicators, which are activated by tapping with two fingers. I'm pretty confident that your commitEditingStyle method is not being triggered, because these gestures are not handled by a UITableView, and are not the swipe gestures that trigger this method. You must figure out why this GESTURE is being used, not why the method isn't working (it may be).

Comment: search where other gesture controllers are in your project

Comment: @dylanthelion thanks for trying to help. It works the same way on a real device. And that method actually works just fine when I'm using alt+swipe. I don't have any custom gesture handlers in my app at all :(

Comment: Pinch and explode are default gestures; whether or not you do anything with them, the device and simulator will recognize them. Your problem may not be with your app. You have to figure out why the device and simulator are recognizing the wrong gestures, and there is nothing in your code that would explain this.